# Spring boot Create first and second level cache

Tags: jpa, caching, spring-boot, time, second-level-cache

With Spring Boot with JPA and Rest I want to 
 •  Create first and second level cache. The first level cache will store data of last 5 mins on memory and second level cache will persist the whole database in the cache memory(Considering data set to be small).

And 
•   Search for data in the first level cache, if found, return data from it else search from the second level cache memory. It should be there in the second level cache.

Please help me how to proceed.

This is my controller class:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/rest")
    @CacheConfig(cacheNames = "EmployeesCache")
    public class EmployeeController {

        @Autowired
        EmployeesRepository employeesRepository;

        @Autowired
        AddressRepository addressRepository;
        @RequestMapping(value = "/dummyEmployees/", me

thod = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> listdummydata() {
        List<Employee> employees = EmployeesRepository.populateDummyEmployees();

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
  -------------------Create an Employee----------------------------------------
    @CachePut(cacheNames="EmployeesCache")
    @PostMapping("/newEmployee/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder)
    {

        employeesRepository.save(emp);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/rest/{id}").buildAndExpand(emp.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

 // -------------------add Address-------------------------------------------
    @CachePut(cacheNames="EmployeesCache")
    @PostMapping("/addAddressToEmployee/{employee_id}")
    public void addAddress(@RequestBody Address address,@PathVariable("employee_id") int employee_id)
    {   Employee emp= new Employee(employee_id,"");
        address.setEmployee(emp);

        addressRepository.save(address);

    }

     // -------------------get Address based in id of address-------------------------------------------    
    @Cacheable()
    @GetMapping("/addressid/{id}")
    public Address getaddress(@PathVariable("id") final Integer id) {
        return addressRepository.findOne(id);
    }


 // -------------------get all employees------------------------------------------- 

    @GetMapping("/all/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAll() {
        List<Employee> employees = employeesRepository.findAll();
        if(employees.isEmpty())
            throw new CustomNotFoundException("Emply table");
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
 // -------------------get employee by id-------------------------------------------    
    @Cacheable()
    @GetMapping("/id/{id}")
    public Employee getId(@PathVariable("id") final Integer id) {
        Employee emp= employeesRepository.findOne(id);
        if(emp== null)
            throw new CustomNotFoundException("Not found employee with id " + id);
        return emp;
    }

 // -------------------get employee by name-------------------------------------------  
    @Cacheable()
    @GetMapping("/name/{name}")
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeByName(@PathVariable("name") final String name) {
        List<Employee> employees= employeesRepository.findByName(name);
        if(employees.isEmpty())
            throw new CustomNotFoundException("Not found employee with name " + name);
        return employees;
    }

 // -------------------get employee by pin code-------------------------------------------  
    @Cacheable()
    @GetMapping("/pincode/{pincode}")
    public List<Employee> getPincode(@PathVariable("pincode") final String pincode) {
        List<Employee> employees= employeesRepository.findEmployeeByPincode(pincode);
        if(employees.isEmpty())
            throw new CustomNotFoundException("Not found employee with pincode " + pincode);
        return employees;
    }

 // -------------------get employee by city ------------------------------------------- 
    @Cacheable()
    @GetMapping("/city/{city}")
    public List<Employee> getCity(@PathVariable("city") final String city) {

        List<Employee> employees= employeesRepository.findEmployeeByCity(city);
        if(employees.isEmpty())
            throw new CustomNotFoundException("Not found employee with city " + city);
        return employees;
    }

}
```

This is ehcache.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">
<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <cache name="EmployeesCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="100"
           eternal="false"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           timeToLiveSeconds="300"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
    </cache>


</ehcache>
```

and this is application file:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username =root
spring.datasource.password =root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect


spring.cache.ehcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
spring.cache.ehcache.provider=net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
```

This is my service class:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "EmployeesCache")
public interface EmployeesRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    List<Employee> findByName(String name);

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
    public static void clearCache(){}



    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e join e.AddressList a WHERE a.pincode =:pincode")
    public List<Employee> findEmployeeByPincode(@Param("pincode") String pincode);



    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e join e.AddressList a WHERE a.city =:city")
    public List<Employee> findEmployeeByCity(@Param("city") String city);

    static List<Employee> populateDummyEmployees(){
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employees.add(new Employee(1,"Sam"));
        employees.add(new Employee(2,"Tom"));
        employees.add(new Employee(3,"Jim"));
        employees.add(new Employee(4,"Git"));
        return employees;
    }

}
```

And this is my configuration class:

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.spring.jpa.service")
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJpaHibernateExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJpaHibernateExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }


}
```

Please help to proceed further

Comment: The first level cache is already managed by JPA, you shouldn't have to care about that. Storing all your data in the second level cache is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll If I have to apply without using JPA. and this is a small assignment I have to do.Please help me with the steps.I will share the code I have done.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll please help

Comment: Sorry  but I don't understand what you're trying to do.